# Difference between Asp.Net Core MVC & Asp.Net Framework MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to create a new web application for my company and I would like doing it with Asp MVC technology. 
So, can you please tell me the difference between an **Asp.Net *Core* MVC** and an **Asp.Net ***Framework*** MVC** application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both do about the same things, but NET Core is newer, faster, multiplatform, easier to test, open source and will become the only one in the long run. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/.
Some stuff (ie Blazor Server) is only available on Core.

Speaking of MVC the only difference I recall is Framework having 2 controllers (one for views and one for API) which has become a single one in Core.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: thank you very much. Short and simple answer, I'm gonna go with Core!